# Can't resolve compile errors in AsyncOnSubscribe

Tags: rx-java

```
Observable<ScanResult> scanResultStream( UUID uuid ) {
    return Observable.create( new AsyncOnSubscribe<Boolean, Subscriber<ScanResult>>() {
        @Override
        Boolean next( Boolean previousState, long requested, Observer<Observable<Subscriber<ScanResult>>> sub) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Have tried everything I can think of but can't get this to compile and as usual the RxJava documentation is not very helpful, and I can't find better examples or explanations.

The problem appears to lie in the second constructor type parameter `<T>` for `AsyncOnSubscribe`, which the documentation says is "the type of `Subscriber`s that will be compatible with this". Taking this literally, I think this should be `<Subscriber<ScanResult>>`, but this doesn't work. I get a message that the class must either be declared abstract or implement `next(S, long, Observer<Observable<? extends T>>)`, but
taking *this* literally, my method signature should be `next(Boolean previousState, long requested, Observer<Observable<Subscriber<ScanResult>>> obs)`, but this produces the message 'Method does not override method from its superclass'.

I'm also getting 'Unchecked assignment: '`rx.Observable<T>` to `rx.Observable<com.polidea.rxandroidble.scan.ScanResult`'.

If I could find a clear explanation of `AsyncOnSubscribe` perhaps I could figure this out. (This all began when I wanted to use `Observable.create( Observable.OnSubscribe)` but found out it was deprecated.)

Comment: First of all, it seems that you are missing an override for protected Boolean generateState(). The proper return type of your method would be Observable<Subscriber<ScanResult>>. Could you please explain what you are trying to do? (using rxjava 1.3.4)

Comment: It all started here: http://adelnizamutdinov.github.io/blog/2015/01/23/using-rxjavas-observable-semantics-for-greater-good/ (2nd code snippet), where I encountered use of     `subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(call::cancel));` to automatically cancel an HTTP request if the user unsubscribes. I wanted to sketch out something similar for possible use, but found that the author used a deprecated form of `Observable.create()`. This led me to the form using `AsyncOnSubscribe`, but I can't figure out how to apply it. (I added the override for `generateState()` but it didn't help.)

Answer (score 0):

Environment:

> RxJava 1.3.4

- This is wrong: Observer>> sub
- Missing imp

Result

```
Observable<ScanResult> scanResultStream(UUID uuid) {
    Observable<ScanResult> scanResultObservable =
        Observable.create(
            new AsyncOnSubscribe<Boolean, ScanResult>() {
              @Override
              protected Boolean generateState() {
                return null;
              }

              @Override
              protected Boolean next(
                  Boolean state,
                  long requested,
                  Observer<Observable<? extends ScanResult>> observer) {
                return null;
              }
            });

    return scanResultObservable;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. That statement in the documentation threw me off: T is "the type of Subscribers that will be compatible with this". Well, the type of *any* Subscriber is `Subscriber`, right? It should say something like "T is the type of item expected by the Subscriber". Some additional explanation of the various methods in `AsyncOnSubscribe` would be appreciated, too. For example, for the `createStateless()` method, what does this mean: "This should be used when the next function closes over it's state." And what exactly is the difference between Async and Sync OnSubscribe?